# Can anyone help me to correct this excel formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In cell `D1`

```
"User Name: Hari Prasad
User ID: INHPR9 
Machine Name: BNGRET-L-99950 
SoldtoCode: 10005625"
```

`D2`

```
"User Name: Stuart Macdonald 
Machine Name: LONSC-L-97778 
SoldtoCode: 10003058"
```

I wrote the fr

`E1`

```
=IF(FIND("User",D1,5),LEFT(D1,FIND("User",D1,5)),LEFT(D1,FIND("Machine",D1)))
```

`E2`

```
=IF(FIND("User",D2,5),LEFT(D2,FIND("User",D2,5)),LEFT(D2,FIND("Machine",D2)))

RESULT
E1=User Name: Hari Prasad

E2=#VALUE ERROR
```

Comment: Please don't forget to accept answers. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this into E2

=IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("User",D2,5))),LEFT(D2,FIND("User",D2,5)),LEFT(D2,FIND("Machine",D2)))

The FIND function returns an error if it cant find the text, which doesn't work as FALSE for the if statement.

Comment: Oh sorry its not working .. it automatically came to 2 when i click tick button :(

Comment: After you accepted the answer, you appear to have unaccepted it again. The 'tick' should be green.